# Is it “…to write to you and let…” or “…to write to you to let…”?

Tags: prepositions, writing-style, conjunctions

I'm writing the sentence

> I wanted to take this opportunity to write to you **and** let you know...",

but I'm wondering if,

> I wanted to take this opportunity to write to you **to** let you know...

would be preferable?

Comment: Yes, it's repetitive to keep using 'to', and you don't need to say 'write to you' when write you conveys the same thing.

Comment: "write you" is an Americanism.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - er, no it's not!  See answer below ;-)

Comment: @Dan, well I'm as surprised as you were :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are workarounds for the OP's question (e.g. answer from user242899), the answer if the question is faced head on, to my English ears, is

"*He said he would write **to you to** let you know...*".

I might say '*and*' instead of '*to you to*'. But I wouldn't usually say '*write you*'.  Although if this usage is acceptable to you (and it is widespread - see below) it solves the OP's problem (*I wanted to take this opportunity to write you and let you know*...").

Surprisingly (to me) '*write you*' and '*write to you*' are *both* contemporary usages in both the US and the UK (according to Ngrams).

> [US English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=write+you%2C+write+to+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrite%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrite%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0)
>
> [UK English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=write+you%2Cwrite+to+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrite%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrite%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0)

And the OED also makes clear that '***write you***' was widely used in the UK in the past - suggesting that my preferred usage is a relatively recent, UK innovation).

> 1598   Shakespeare ***Henry IV, Pt. 1*** iv. i. 31   *He writes me here that [etc.]* .
>
> a1706   J. Evelyn ***Life Mrs. Godolphin*** (1939) 52   *She writes me..what Conflicts she had indur'd*.
>
> 1843   R. T. Lowe ***Fishes Madeira I***. 101   *Mr. Yarrell writes me word that [etc.]*.

Comment: Nope, sorry, I'm just blunt, I lack social graces. The OP expressed uncertainty between  "... **to** let you know" vs "... **and** let you know" so I don't see the relevancy of your proposed edit? And you pay greater attention in your answer to the "write you" when the OP never asked about that in the first place.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes I realise I do.  Mainly because it provides an answer to the OP's question, provided you are happy to use it (which I'm not, at present - although who's to say if I hear it often enough...).  I've edited my answer to try and make it clearer.

Comment: I still don't get why you modified the OP's sentence, but your answer is clearer, so I have deleted two comments! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think I was wanting to make it shorter without wanting to alter the important stuff...

Answer (score 5):

I think that you are trying avoid using  the preposition **to** too many times. If this is the case then how about the following sentence:

> I am writing to let you know...

This conveys the same message without repeating  the preposition **to** and the article **the**. You could also say:

> I am taking this opportunity to let you know...

You don't have to mention that you are **writing** as it is obvious since the recipient has your letter. I hope that helps you.

*Source: None, except experience as a native speaker.*

Comment: Good point. Taking this a little further would edit out the whole quote prior to the "...". E.g. *Original*: "Dear Sir, I wanted to ... let you know **your order has arrived**." *Edited to*: "Dear Sir, **Your order has arrived**." There might be emotional/courtesy value in the padding, though.

Comment: BUT both this answer and the comment above are 'workarounds' that are dodging the question!

Comment: I agree that 'writing' is superfluous, but something like 'I am letting you know that...' feels a bit terse. I suppose 'I wanted to let you know that...' is more agreeable, though.

Comment: @James one of the suggested answers is "I am writing to let you know" which flows and sounds very natural. The verb "write" is not omitted.